# Standard Normal Variance Integral

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, integration

I am having troubles with the below integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{{-x^2}/{2}}  dx$$

In particular, I am getting $2$ instead of $1$ and I guess this is caused by $$\frac{d}{dx} x^2 = 2x$$.

This is what I'm doing:
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{{-x^2}/{2}} = $$ $$ = \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\left[ x^2 \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{-x}\right]^\infty_{-\infty} - \cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \color{red}2x \frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{-x}  dx= $$
$$= \frac{\color{red}2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2/2} dx = $$ $$ = \frac{\color{red}2}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sqrt{2\pi} = \color{red}2$$

I understand that that $2x$ inside the second integral should get simplified, but I can't figure out how.
Can you help?

Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your answers guys, it works if I consider $\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} x^2 e^{{-x^2}/{2}}$ as $\cfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \color{red} x \cdot \color{blue} {x e^{{-x^2}/{2}}}$, but what if I take $x^2$ instead of $x$? Where is the error in what I'm doing? Is that in the integral of  $e^{-x^2/2}$?

Answer (score 1):

Taking out the $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ for convenience, you should be integrating by parts $\int u \; dv = uv - \int v \; du$ with $u = x$, $dv = x e^{-x^2/2}\; dx$, so $du = dx$ and $v = -e^{-x^2/2}$.  There is no $2$.

Comment: You need a minus sign for $v$.

Comment: Thanks for catching that.  Editing.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @user295357, could you please clarify why $\int e^{-x^2/2}$ should be $\frac{e^{-x^2/2}}{-\color{red}2x}$?

Comment: No, it isn't.  $\int e^{-x^2/2}\; dx$ is not an elementary function at all.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake. Please ignore my above comment which I just deleted.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are getting the indefinite integral of $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ to  be  $\frac{e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}}{-x}$.  That's wrong.

To integrate by parts:  $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^2e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=[-xe^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}]_{-\infty}^\infty+\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx=\sqrt{2\pi}$